# Immediate storage of combined DTC - Dem AUTOSAR

Tags: diagnostics, autosar, non-volatile

Is it correct behaviour of Dem module if it's saving for combined DTC (with immediate storage enabled) only snapshots and extended data? After power reset and read DTC I'm receiving status of DTC 0x50 but with occurence counter equal to one and with snapshot data. For not-combined DTCs status is different than 0x50. Is it correct?

Comment: Did you check, if NvM is up, and if Dem retrieves the Blocks themselves, or if you shall integrate the Dem NvM Blocks to the NvM_ReadAll()? Also, what do you mean reset? Storing only at Shutdown means, normal shutdown, e.g. CL30 devices going to sleep, but CL15 have no real Shutdown-procedure, as CL15 off can happen any time without enough time and power left to do a proper shutdown. The Dem usually initializes the EventStatus to 0x50 (TestNotCompleted-flags), to see if your monitors have reported at all, then usually merges with the flags from last op-cycle (incl NvM status restored).

Answer (score 1):

That behavior for sure is incorrect. State 0x50 indicates that DTC is not tested at all, but on the other side, you have stored data for one of the events mapped to this DTC. Below is your DTC status byte:
[image: problematic DTC status byte]

What we know:

1. The DEM stores the status bytes for all of DTCs in one block, but extended data and snapshots are stored in a separate block.
2. The status byte for combined DTCs is evaluated based on the following table:
   [image]
3. The storage strategy of events are defined by parameter DemEventMemoryEntryStorageTrigger in DEM general options.

I suggest to first check the status of the problematic DTC before reset. If we have in memory snapshot and/or extended data and a status byte which indicates a fail of the DTC, but after reset we have a status 0x50, than it means that the NvM block with the status byte is not triggered to be stored.

But if we also have a status 0x50 before reset, than it means that probably you have only problem with the configuration of DemEventMemoryEntryStorageTrigger.

Comment: Before reset status of DTC is correct (0x2F) but after reset we have 0x50. Block with DTC statuses is not triggered on immediate storage for any DTC (only on shutdown) but after reset statuses for normal DTCs are restored, for combined not.

Comment: 1. In that case is clear that NvM block with DTC statuses is not triggered to storage when immediate DTC occurs, so it also should not work for normal DTC. 
 
2. Lets check option **DemEventCombinationSupport** and try to enable **DEM_EVCOMB_ONRETRIEVAL**:
 
3. If this does not help then you need to contact your vendor of the diagnostic stack or prepare some workaround. For example for this kind of immediate event, configure callback on data event changed and inside this function explicitly triggers storage of DTC statuses block.